# Testing LWC component using jest-cucumber but createElement not working as expected

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I am writing a tests for my LWC component using [jest-cucumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-cucumber). This is my test:

```
defineFeature(feature, test => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    
    element = createElement('c-myLwcElement', {
      is: myLwcElement,
    });
  })

});
```

but `createElement` (imported from 'lwc') is not working as expected. The element is created but `connectedCallback` is not called. In contrast, here is my generated jest test:

```
describe('c-myLwcElement', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });

    it('TODO: test case generated by CLI command, please fill in test logic', async () => {
        // Arrange
        const element = createElement('c-myLwcElement', {
            is: Aggriddatatablev2qed,
        });

        element.objectApiName = 'Asset';

        // Act
        // document.body.appendChild(element);

        // Assert
        // const div = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('div');
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Here, `connectedCallback` is called correctly for my component.

What is wrong with my setup in my `jest-cucumber` test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag name should be in kebab case:

```
const element = createElement('c-my-lwc-element', {
    is: Aggriddatatablev2qed,
});
```

Also, make sure that `Aggriddatatablev2qed` is imported and extends `LightningElement`.

In addition, `connectedCallback` won't be called if you don't add it to the DOM:

```
// document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Should be:

```
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Finally, before querying a child from the element, you have to wait a render cycle, which we typically do with `Promise.resolve`:

```
// Assert
await Promise.resolve();
const div = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('div');
```